# Why should I create interfaces for my concrete DataProvider classes

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net, dao

I use much Microsoft SQL Server propriate stuff.
I do not need multiple concrete classes implementing the same interface.

So why should my DataProvider classes need an interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create interfaces in order to make testing code that depends on your data easier.

Having interfaces and coding to these interfaces means you can inject mocks and stubs in your tests.

Comment: I do not unit-test my DataProvider classes. I do integration tests with my service layer. Thus there is no need for an interface in my dataprovider class. Thus I do not need to mock anything. Where I use mocking is in my asp.net mvc controllers with my service interfaces but that makes sense.

Comment: It's more so you can more easily unit test classes that consume the DataProvider classes. When you have to deal with complicated scenarios (imagine a bug that only occurs when the data in 4 tables is set in a certain way) it is much easier to be able to mock out your Repositories to return the data you expect than it is to set up the database to always return that data. Plus, if you're relying on the database to return certain data, you're writing integration tests, not true unit tests.

Comment: @rsbarro Thus I wrote I do integration tests which is not less good than doing unit tests.

Comment: Imagine this scenario: you have a class that is supposed to write out a message based on the value of a field in the database. The field in the database can have 20 unique values. To handle testing this class with integration tests, you would need 20 database records each with a different value. To handle this with a mockable Repository would require 0 records in the database, because you would just set up a mock that would return the values you need for testing. That approach is easier and less prone to error (since another developer could potentially change your test records).

Comment: If you don't feel the need to use this approach, that's fine, but you asked why should you do it. As @Oded and I both mentioned, a big reason to do so is for mocking/testing purposes.

Comment: but the purpose of integration tests is to test the database wether the data I put in comes out as expected. If I would use mocking I would not do a REAL testing of the database.

Comment: @Pascal - There are many types of integration tests. If you simply want to test between the UI and business logic and not involve the DB, so you know you have a repeatable test that is not dependent on the state of the DB, this would be how to do it.

Comment: @Oded But that mock can`t be a replacement for a real db returning me the values! can it ?

Comment: @Pascal - For the sake of a unit test or integration test (that tests integration between layers that do not include the DB), sure, why not?

Comment: @Oded my last comment ;-) A mock object cannot be created for a concrete class thus I should use an interface you say "indirectly" but this is incorrect. The tool determines what can be mocked and TypeMock and JustMock etc can mock concrete classes. So there seems no reason for me anymore to use an interface for my dataprovider classes right?

Comment: well I do not mind I do not expected any disadvantages from this :)

Answer (score 1):

There are probably many ways to answer this, but one advantage of using an interface (especially with a pattern like the Repository pattern) on your DataProvider is so you can mock that interface, allowing you to unit test the code that makes use of the DataProvider more easily.